# Maximizing the logarithm of a rational function over a polytope

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Which optimization technique/algorithm can be used to solve such problems?
I want to know the name of a technique because some problems I need to solve are more complex than this one.

\begin{align}
\max_{x_1,x_2}\quad \log_{2}(1+\dfrac{x_1}{x_2+0.1})+\log_{2}(1+\dfrac{x_2}{x_1+0.1})\\
s.t\quad\quad \log_{2}(1+\dfrac{x_2}{x_1+0.1})\geq0.1\\\quad \log_{2}(1+\dfrac{x_1}{x_2+0.1})\geq0.1 \\x_1\geq0,x_2\geq0\\
x_1\leq5,x_2\leq5
\end{align}

Comment: please don't tell me that the optimal solution is given by this
\begin{align}
x_{2}=(2^{0.1}-1)5.1\\
x_{1}=5
\end{align}
Thell me the name of an optimization technique that can solve this.

Comment: I want an answer like, "use sequential quadratic programming","use particle swarm optimization" etc
any technique that is sophisticated like SQP.

Comment: I don't want the a answer of this problem. I want the name of an optimization technique that would work on this problem and problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following inequality constraint

$$\log_{2} \left( 1 + \dfrac{x_j}{x_i+0.1} \right) \geq 0.1$$

and rewrite it as follows

$$\dfrac{x_j}{x_i+0.1} \geq 2^{0.1} - 1$$

Given the nonnegativity constraint $x_i \geq 0$, we can multiply both sides by $x_i+0.1$, which yields the following linear inequality

$$\left(2^{0.1} - 1\right) x_i - x_j \leq -\left(2^{0.1} - 1\right) 0.1$$

Thus, we conclude that the feasible region is a **polygon**, namely, a *quadrilateral*.

[image]

- Parametrizing each of the $4$ line segments that form the quadrilateral, we can find the maximum of the objective function on the **boundary** of the feasible region.
- Computing the gradient of the objective function and finding *whether* it vanishes in the interior of the feasible region and, if so, *where* it does vanish, we can find the maximum of the objective function in the **interior** of the feasible region (when it actually does exist).

Taking the maximum of these two maxima, we obtain the desired maximum.